# Adjust the running total automatically when rows deleted to its corresponding date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
ID   Date        Value    RunningTotal
1  25-01-2000   -855       0
2  23-01-2000    855       855
3  22-01-2000    0         0
4  20-01-2000    1200      1200
```

In this table_test

```
select *
from table_test
order by date desc
```

If I delete any row in the table, the dates should readjust the running total.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your best bet is to not store the running total and only compute it when you need it.

Comment: runningtotal column needs to be updated when any of the row is deleted.
How can it be done?

Comment: If you really have to (bad idea), second to worst option, create A stored procedure to handle the delete which carries out the update. Worst option a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Use a view!

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*, sum(value) over (order by id) as running_total
    from t;
```

This will recalculate the total when the data is *queried* so it is always accurate.  With an index on `(id, value)`, performance should be quite reasonable on smallish tables (up to tens of thousands of rows).

If performance is an issue, then you could use an indexed view -- the ways that SQL Server implements materialized views.

Although you *could* implement this as a trigger, that would mean basically updating all (or on average half) the rows in a table when a single row changes.  That is quite expensive and probably the wrong approach to solving your problem.